# altering a key for a value in std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, key-value

I need to alter the key for a given value in std::map. So I've written this method:

```
bool alter_key(_Kty oldKey, _Kty newKey)
{
    std::map<_Kty, _Ty>::iterator it = this->find(newKey);
    if(it != end()) //can't replace because newKey is already been used.
        return false;

    it = this->find(oldKey);
    if(it == end()) // empty index.
        return false;

    _Ty value = it->second;
    this->erase(it);
    this->insert(std::pair<_Kty, _Ty>(newKey, value));
    return true;
}
```

It works as it should be, but is it possible to optimize this code?

Comment: You've profiled your application and found this to be a bottleneck?

Comment: If the mapped_type is expensive to copy, make it a unique/shared_ptr.

Comment: Yes, it is critical for speed, but unfortunately I'm not a skilled c++ developer.

Comment: So which part is your identified bottleneck?, The map insertion (where nothing you do will make it faster) or the object copying?

Comment: Copying objects if _Ty is not a pointer.

Comment: @user2708147: In that case, moving (or swapping, if you're stuck with pre-2011 semantics) would be faster for some types. It won't help if the objects are large, but will if they manage other objects via pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to speed up that particular operation, then maybe `std::map` is not the right choice for the container. That being said, it might also be the right choice, so the next question is what is there to optimize in that function, what is the higher cost in the function? Is it the lookups? The cost of creating the new element?

If the higher cost is the copying of data, then you might want to consider avoiding copies in the algorithm. Instead of copying from the container to a local variable and then doing an extra copy to insert into the destination you can skip the intermediate copy:

```
insert(std::make_pair(new_key,it->value));
erase(it);
```

If the `value` is costly to copy but can be moved (either rvalue-reference move, or it is cheap to default construct and you can swap the contents), you can exploit it:

```
insert(std::make_pair(new_key,std::move(it->value)));
// alternatively in C++03, for example for large strings or std::vector<> values
value_type& x = *insert(std::make_pair(new_key,ValueType())).first;
swap(x,it->value);
```

Note how things become more convoluted and harder to understand/maintain.

Another thing that you can improve is the lookup. Currently you do three lookups into the container: two to determine the existence of the old and new keys, and a third one to insert. You can reduce that. If you attempt an insert and the key is already there, it won't be modified, so you could do:

```
using std::swap;
iterator it = find(old_key);
if (it == end()) return false;
std::pair<bool, iterator> ins_res = insert(std::make_pair(new_key,ValueType()));
if (!ins_res.second) return false;
swap(it->second,ins_res.first->second); // swap contents
erase(it);
```

But still, consider whether a `std::map` is the right choice for your data structure... for example if lookups are expensive and ordering is not important, then `std::unordered_map` as it might have better lookup performance.

Comment: Thank you so much, but for my task uniqueness of keys is important.

Comment: @user2708147: *uniqueness* was never discussed, *order* and *uniqueness* are not the same thing. Both `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` provide the same uniqueness guarantees, it is just that the underlying data structure and thus the complexities differ. Maintaining the data sorted (as in `std::map`) is more expensive than just guaranteeing uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you again, David! I read about std::unordered_map at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map), and this is exactly what I needed.